# glfw + glew : unresolved external symbol with older functions

Tags: opengl, glew, glfw

I have some issues with glfw3 and glew.

Here is the code :

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3dll.lib")

#include <iostream>

#include "GLEW\glew.h"
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"

void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    std::cerr << description << std::endl;
}

void input_callback(GLFWwindow* wnd, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) glfwSetWindowShouldClose(wnd,      GL_TRUE);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//init glfw
if(!glfwInit()) return EXIT_FAILURE;

//error callback
glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

//create window with opengl 4.3 core profil context
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "glfw openGL", NULL, NULL);
if(!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//input callback
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, input_callback);

//binding context
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

//init glew
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if(GLEW_OK != glewInit())
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//generate a vertex buffer object
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

//set clear color
glClearColor(100.f/255, 149.f/255, 237.f/255, 1.0);

//main loop
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

//destroy window
glfwDestroyWindow(window);

//terminate glfw
glfwTerminate();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And here are the errors i get :

```
error LNK2019: symbole externe non rÚsolu __imp__glClear@4 rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction _main C:\Users\Adrien\Documents\CPP\GlfwSetup\GlfwSetup\main.obj  GlfwSetup

error LNK2019: symbole externe non rÚsolu __imp__glClearColor@16 rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction _main   C:\Users\Adrien\Documents\CPP\GlfwSetup\GlfwSetup\main.obj  GlfwSetup
```

If I comment the glClearColor and glClear lines the program runs well (even the glGenBuffers part). So I don't understand why I can use some openGl functions but can't use some others.

OS : windows 7 64 bits.
IDE : visual studio 2012 express.
glfw version : 3.
glew version 1.10.0.

Comment: "*And here are the errors i get :*" Translation? Also, I don't see the part where you included the OpenGL library.

Comment: Sorry, my english is pretty bad. Well you're right I added the "#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib") line and it works. I checked at my previous OpenGL program and I guess freeGLUT included the opengl library for me. So I forgot to include it. Thank you very much. Now I'm gonna take some english courses :).

Comment: If you have resolved your question yourself, you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

I actually forgot to link the OpenGL library.

Thank you for the help.